# how i can retrieve 50 records using Tumblr API?

Tags: api, social-networking, tumblr, pytumblr

by default Tumblr API retrieve 20 records:

> https://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=love&api_key=Key

and I want to get 50 records and I have also tried this:

> https://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=love&limit=50&api_key=Key

but still getting 20 records. anybody tell me how I can get 50 records?

Answer (score 1):

[The Tumblr API's `/tagged` endpoint](https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#tagged--get-posts-with-tag) only allows limits between 1-20 inclusive. If you ask for any other limits, it looks like it defaults to their default value, which in this case is 20.

You could use the oldest retrieved post's timestamp, to then ask for 20 more posts from before-the-oldest-returned-post's-timestamp (since the endpoint supports a `before` query parameter). That would look something like this:

- GET 20 posts
- Find the oldest post from the response
- GET 20 more posts before that oldest post (something like `https://api.tumblr.com/v2/tagged?tag=love&api_key=Key&before=...oldest-post's-timestamp...`)
- Repeat

But other than that there's no way to bypass their limit.

Comment: This is right, but there is also an offset parameter, so if you are retrieving 20 posts, you set the offset to 21 and then you increment it each time via a loop function.

Comment: I've not used the API before personally, just read the documentation. Is that parameter documented anywhere?

Comment: Yes have a look here: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/api/v2#posts--retrieve-published-posts it's the 7th attribute. If you get stuck I have some working examples on jsfiddle

Comment: Ah that's brilliant. Shame it isn't documented in the tagged endpoint too, lol.